# Use decorated WCF entity class without referencing service itself

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have a service, which produced a class, let's say `OperationDesc` in `MyProject.Proxy`. I want to have my class, that wraps some of the properties of `OperationDesc`. So I've created a class `OperationView` in `MyProject.Entity` and derieved it from `OperationDesc`.

```
namespace MyProject.Proxy {

    public class OperationDesc {

        public long Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace MyProject.Entity {

    using Proxy;

    public class OperationView : OperationDesc {

        public string DateString {
            get 
            {
                return Created.ToString();
            }
        }    
    }
}

namespace MyProject.Web {

    using Entity;

    public class HomeController : Controller {

        public ActionResult(){
            var operation = ... logic ...;
            operation.Id <--- require Proxy reference
        }

    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to use `OperationView` in `MyProject.Web`, using reference to `MyProject.Entity`. But I can't access `OperationDesc` properties, unless I reference `Proxy` library, what I don't want to do. **Can you suggest any pattern or approach I need to use here?** The main goal is to decorate service class with some additional properties, without referencing `Proxy` library. Ofc I can copy all properties from `OperationDesc` to `OperationView` and use AutoMapper, but it looks like antipattern. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a service oriented architecture, it's assumed that the server, and the client are completely different applications. So, the client shouldn't have any information about your service implementations, including model classes which you created with c#. Client may be JavaScript or JAVA/Android or RoR application. So, the C# created models (classes) are completely unusable in client-side. For clients, what does matter, is the protocol you are defining. So, say you have this model in server-side (wcf project):

```
public class OperationDesc {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

What clients need to know, is something like this:

```
type OperationDesc {
    Id (Int64),
    Created (DateTime)
}
```

nothing more. So each client may have its own implementation from the model:

JavaScript:

```
function OperationDesc(){
    this.Id = 0;
    this.Created = new Date(); // or null or anything else
}
```

JAVA:

```
public class OperationDesc {
    private Long id;
    private Date created;

    public void setId(Long value) { this.id = value; }
    public Long getId() { return this.id; }

    public void setCreated(Date value) { this.created= value; }
    public Date getCreated() { return this.created; }
}
```

C#:

```
public class OperationDesc {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you have defined your protocol and you can see any type of client applications, can communicate with your service. Well, in your particular application, you need an extra property? OK, no problem:

```
public class OperationDesc {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string DateString {
        get 
        {
            return Created.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

(Or you can create a pure `OperationDesc` class and a

```
public class OperationView : OperationDesc {

    public string DateString {
        get 
        {
            return Created.ToString();
        }
    }    
}
```

as you was trying to do with your server-side entity. But this time, `OperationDesc` is not a class in your server-app, it's a whole new class in client-app).

So, no, creating a class in client-side and copy all properties and using AutoMapper is not anti-pattern at all.

**BUT:**

If you really don't care about SOA and you just want to avoiding repeat, you may create a class-library projects and put all you models there (just models) and share that lib in all projects (including service and web-client). I don't suggest that of-course.

Comment: Thx, guess I got it :)